# Column rename not working in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, rename

I am looking to rename the last 2 columns as `country` and `active`:

```
airlines.rename(columns={6 : 'country',7 : 'active'},inplace=True).
```

I have attached a screenshot of the top 5 rows before and after. You will see that the column rename does not work. Any help why this would be appreciated.

[image: data set]

Comment: Is your current column name 6 and 7?? and we don't see any screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

This will change your last two columns:

```
airlines.columns = [*airlines.columns[:-2],'country','active']
```

Comment: Thanks that works fine, do you have any idea why my code did not work ? it did not generate any errors just did not perform the rename. Also  I have attached the screenshot, but for somereason does not appear on the post.

Comment: Yeah, I checked your screenshot while trying to edit. Replace is meant for matching exact string case and replacing it with the one we provide. In your data, there's no column called 6 or 7. Instead, you could've done `airlines.rename(columns={airlines.columns[6]: 'country',airlines.columns[7] : 'active'},inplace=True)`.

Comment: Ok thanks that explains it much appreciated . It is part of a course on Dataquest and the code I wrote worked in their environment but not in jupyter notebook. Hence my confusion. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure.Happy Coding!

Comment: @somace please consider [accepting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped you.